# How can I cast an object to a Func<In, Out> without knowing the generics?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, async-await, casting

I have a ton of functions that all accept a class (Request) and return a class (Response) and I'm trying to write a generic handler.

I can't change the definition of my class `JobParametersModel` to accept generics or my method `DoWorkAsync`, but I can modify everything else.

Given these classes:

```
public class JobRequestModel<Request, Response>
    where Request : class
    where Response : class
{
    public Func<Request, Task<Response>> CallDelegate { get; set; }

    public async Task<Response> DoCall(Request request)
    {
        return await CallDelegate(request);
    }
}

public sealed class JobParametersModel
{
    // Stores class JobRequestModel and other params
    public object RequestModel { get; set; }
}
```

**This is the method I'm trying to solve.** How can I get the object to something I can interact with?

```
// What I'm trying to do, that does not work.
public async Task<JobResultModel> DoWorkAsync(JobParametersModel work, object request)
{
    var jobRequestModel = (JobRequestModel)work.RequestModel; // Does NOT work.
    
    // I can cast request using "ChangeType". Simplified code for example
    var results = await jobRequestModel.DoCall(request);
    
    // I package/return results later
}
```

That way I can call it like this:

```
var result1 = await DoWorkAsync(
    new JobParametersModel()
    {
        RequestModel = new JobAXRequestModel<CustomRequestType, CustomResponseType>()
        {
            CallDelegate = _client.getMyCustomDelegate
        }
    },
    new CustomRequestType()
    {
        CustomField1 = "something",
        CustomField2 = 4
    }
);

var result2 = await DoWorkAsync(
    new JobParametersModel()
    {
        RequestModel = new JobAXRequestModel<OtherCustomRequestType, OtherCustomResponseType>()
        {
            CallDelegate = _client.getSomeOtherCustomDelegate
        }
    },
    new OtherCustomRequestType()
    {
        DifferentField1 = "other things"
    }
);
```

Comment: Given that you have to write `RequestModel = new JobAXRequestModel<CustomRequestType, CustomResponseType>()` anyway, can you not simply have `public async Task<JobResultModel> DoWorkAsync<Request, Response>(JobParametersModel work, object request) where Request : class where Response : class` and in there `var jobRequestModel = (JobRequestModel<Request, Response>)work.RequestModel;`?

Comment: The code is simplified, but it's actually part of a larger queueing/polling framework. I don't call that method directly so I can't modify that function definition without rewriting the entire framework unfortunately.

Comment: That contradicts the *I can't change the definition of my class `JobParametersModel` to accept generics, but I can modify everything else* :)

Comment: Perhaps you could throw in a few ducks and replace `var jobRequestModel = (JobRequestModel)work.RequestModel` with `dynamic jobRequestModel = work.RequestModel` - once it becomes dynamic, then you should be able to invoke the `DoCall` method as long as the signatures match.

Comment: @MetroSmurf it looks like I was able to get that to work! Is that the best way to access the generic or should I add more reflection checks?

Comment: As long as the signature isn't expected to change, then additional checks are unnecessary. However, if the `request` in `DoWorkAsync(JobParametersModel work, object request)` may be some other type, then you'll want to verify the method exists first.

Comment: Makes sense! If you put it in an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scenarios where a method must be implemented using a pre-defined signature, but you need to access some other type, then the option of duck-typing within the method exists.

For reference, see: [Using type dynamic (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

In you sample code, the following method must be implemented with the following signature:

```cs
Task<JobResultModel> DoWorkAsync(JobParametersModel work, object request)
```

Where the `JobParametersModel` type contains an `object` with the model:

```cs
public object RequestModel { get; set; }
```

As you cannot change either the signature of the `DoWorkAsync` method, nor the structure of the `JobParametersModel`, then you can take advantage of dynamic programming and bypass compile time checking with runtime validation:

```cs
dynamic jobRequestModel = work.RequestModel
```

Where the final implementation will be:

```cs
public async Task<JobResultModel> DoWorkAsync(JobParametersModel work, object request)
{
    // cast the the model to a dynamic type
    // could also be defined as: 
    // dynamic jobRequestModel = work.RequestModel
    var jobRequestModel = (dynamic)work.RequestModel;
    
    // invoke the method; type checking will only during runtime
    var results = await jobRequestModel.DoCall(request);
    
    // other code...
}
```

As long as the method exists on the `dynamic` type, then the runtime will execute the method. However, if the method does not exist or has a different signature, then a runtime exception will be thrown.

If you expect to have types other than a `JobRequestModel` be passed in as the `RequestModel`, then you'll want to perform additional checking to verify the type before invoking the method (could be as simple as reflection to find a matching method).

Comment: I thought "duck" was a typo. I had no idea that was a thing, thanks for clarifying as well!

Comment: jaja! yeah, duck-typing is a funny term. Coming from a statically typed background, dynamic programming can be a bit odd at first. Cheers!